# how to detect user is inside car without using Awarness API in android?

Tags: android, user-activity

Please help me how to detect driver is inside car or not, means vehicle is moving or not? even if application kill( A kind of Broadcast receiver which Broadcast even app terminate )

I have tried with Activity recognition but here I need to open activity, if I will terminate app, will not get any call back.

Please help me or suggest me any solution for this for Android.
thank you

Comment: You need to use pending Intent

Comment: have you tried with a service?